# Thymeleaf - How to call template html page from static html page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm developing a Spring boot application using Thymeleaf as the view technology. I have a html page dashboard.html inside src/main/resources/templates folder, which is being called from inside a controller.

[image]

```
@PostMapping("/users/register")
public String registerUser(@Validated @ModelAttribute User user, Model model) {
    User registeredUser = usersDAO.registerUser(user);

    if (registeredUser == null) {
        return "500error";
    }

    model.addAttribute("name", user.getName());
    model.addAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
    model.addAttribute("emailId", user.getEmailId());

    return "dashboard";
}
```

I have some more static html files inside `static` folder. I want to call `dashboard.html` from a static html file like using anchor tag `<a/>`. How can this be done?

I cannot directly link to this file when my app is running locally. For example: `localhost:8080/templates/dashboard.html` will not work.

Comment: Not really your question here, but important: In the case that the user is `null`, you should not just show a proper error page but also ensure the proper HTTP code is used. With the current code, you will still return a 200 OK. The easiest way is to throw an exception that is annotated with `@ResponseStatus`.

Comment: src/main/resources is not a good location to store html pages

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez `src/main/resources/templates` is the default location if you use Spring Boot with the Thymeleaf starter. I do agree that is is strange to have some html pages in the `static` subdirectory. Mostly this is used for CSS, JS and/or image files.

Comment: You are right sory

Comment: Spring boot creates jar file I forgot it. So webapp does not exist

Answer (score 2):

You should create a controller for your `thymeleaf` html template. For example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/templates")
public class DashboardController {

    @GetMapping("/dashboard")
    public ModelAndView dashboard() {
        DashboardModel dashboardModel = new DashboardModel();
        return new ModelAndView("dashboard", "dashboard", dashboardModel);
    }

}
```

Then you can link to `http://localhost:8080/templates/dashboard` and get your dashboard.html page.

Of course you can change the `@RequestMapping("/templates")` and `@GetMapping("/dashboard")` to control the url as you like.

Comment: Note that you don't _need_ to use `/templates` in the `@RequestMapping` of the controller, this can be anything you like and it will still work.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe, of course :) i used the `/templates/dashboard` because of the url pattern he mentioned as an example. edited my answer with you remarks.